# Existing ubuntu image convert to reburn dvd for installation

Tags: ubuntu-one

so my buddy had a local pc shop put ubuntu on his home desktop though now he wants that same version installed onto his vista laptop he's otherwise  done with. I offered to help

This is what i need to do: Get the same ubuntu version onto his laptop because that's what he's familiar with and doesn't care to learn the new version...if at all possible.

Ubuntu Version 11.10

Is there a way to get the old version/that version of Ubuntu or burn a dvd using the current install? I found the below url though if someone can confirm that it is valid d installs that'd comfort me. I don't want to go through all the steps to find it isnt or something is wrong.

Thank you for reading and helping!

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.10/

Comment: The url is valid. But even though he is familiar with 11.10, please advise to spend some time to learn the latest ones. Because 11.10 is not supported any more. The new LTS ones(12.04 or 14.04) can be tweaked to feel like 11.10. On 11.10, he would miss out on critical updates and someday might ditch Ubuntu because it was not secure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is exactly the site where you need to get the old releases' ISOs from.

However, it is **disrecommended** to install a End Of Life version of Ubuntu. You will receive neither real support, nor any security updates.

I doubt your friend will have problems with using Trusty or Utopic, since both use Unity as their default Desktop Environment, like Oneiric does. I doubt that your friend will even notice any difference.

If, however, you still plan to install Oneiric on his computer, you are free to do so. Then just get the correct ISO from the link in your question.

---

PS: If you have an USB stick with more than 1GB, use UNetBootin to extract the ISO to this **empty** stick. It will then behave like an Ubuntu DVD on boot. After the installation, you can wipe the stick and use it normally again. This will save you a DVD.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the_seppi! 

I didn't realize the EOL/End Of Life/Support part so I do really appreciate you mentioning this to me. I'll push the buttons and get him to a newer version because you had me at "You will receive neither real support..." though "...any security updates." sealed the deal. Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW the_Seppi do you know if it is possible to clonezilla one ubuntu install to then restore onto different hardware like the other answer hints at?

Answer (score 1):

Use Clonezilla, clone the hard drive to an external and restore it to the new drive.

http://clonezilla.org/

Alternatively, you can also just swap the hard drive from the old machine to the new one.

The URL for the old download is correct, just verify if it is 32 or 64 bit they currently have installed and download and use the correct version!

Comment: they are both 32bit machines so that takes some of the work out of the equation.

I just recently learned how to clonezilla my own ubuntu 14.04....are you hinting at the mindblowing possibility that with clonezilla you can restore an "image" or a "backup" via clonezilla onto a machine that doesn't have the same hardware? You would probably be making my month 'cause then it would make life so much easier lol.

I'm not going to touch hard drives because I have yet to build my own laptop. Definitely on my bucketlist lol.